# How to make modifies in JobDataMap visible in another context?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, quartz.net, quartz

I have ReloadJob that modify all other  JobDataMap in scheduler, and the problem that when I try to get jobdetail from another context (in another job) it returned me empty map. I know that changes are visible only in current context. But maybe there is some solution to make it visible to all scheduler's jobs?
`

```
[PersistJobDataAfterExecution]
    [DisallowConcurrentExecution]
    public class ReloadJob : IJob
    {
        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
           try
            {
                GetJobs();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                JobExecutionException jex = new JobExecutionException(ex, false);
                throw jex;
            }
    
        }

        private async void GetJobs()
        {
            IScheduler scheduler = await SchedulerRepository.Instance.Lookup("ConsoleScheduler");
            var jobGroups = scheduler.GetJobGroupNames().Result;
            foreach (string group in jobGroups)
            {
                var groupMatcher = GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupContains(group);
                var jobKeys = scheduler.GetJobKeys(groupMatcher).Result;
                foreach (var jobKey in jobKeys)
                {
                    var detail = scheduler.GetJobDetail(jobKey).Result;
                    var triggers = scheduler.GetTriggersOfJob(jobKey).Result;
                    detail.JobDataMap.Put("Reload", "yes");
                    foreach (ITrigger trigger in triggers)
                    {
                        
                        Console.WriteLine(detail.JobType.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine(detail.JobDataMap.Get("Reload"));
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

```
Here how i take it in another job
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var temp = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;
       
    }
```

The attributes `[PersistJobDataAfterExecution] [DisallowConcurrentExecution]` only work in context where changes were made

Comment: Could you please share the details of `another context (in another job)` how its been called and configured?

Comment: Job is configured in Startup.ConfigureServices inside AddQuartz extension method, the scheduling is like: q.ScheduleJob<Test>(trigger => trigger.StartAt(...).WithSimpleSchedule(...));
That's all configuration for the job